# Symfony2 -- Creating a form that use's differents entities

Tags: php, symfony

I've been using Symfony a bit and i'm trying to figure out a way to create a form.
I need to use a MVC based solution.

My form needs to ask several information of different Entities and then i need to process that information extracting it in the database.
The database wont be a problem.

I was just figuring out how do i make a form with different types of entities ?

And how do i make a scrolldown menu with the data contained in the database for an entity ?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html you can map the association as a field of your form, adding choices you will get a select element containing options with a property (of your choice) of the related entity as value.

Answer (score 0):

If the comment by @chalasr does not apply, i.e., the entities are not related, it is possible to do something like the following in a controller.  Simply create a $form variable for each Entity{x}Type form as in:

```
$formA = $this->createForm(AppBundle\Entity\EntityAType($entityA));
$formB = $this->createForm(AppBundle\Entity\EntityBType($entityB));
...

return array(
    'formA' => $formA->createView(),
    'formB' => $formB->createView(),
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply combine the Forms while keeping each separate like so

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ReallyBigFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('foo', FooType::class, [
                // label, required, ... as well as options of FooType
            ])
            ->add('bar', BarType::class, [
                // label, required, ... as well as options of BarType
            ])
        ;

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([]);
    }

}
```

and define `FooType` and `BarType` like a regular Form

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType

class FooType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'foo.name',
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Foo',
        ]);
    }

}
```